# Convert CIColor to UIColor with Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicolor

I have a variable which is of type [CIColor](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coreimage/cicolor?language=objc) :

```
var ciColor = getColorFromUI()
```

when I print the ciColor by `print(ciColor)`, the output is this:

```
Optional((1 0.78 0 1))
```

Is there a way to convert this `CIColor` value to a [UIColor](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicolor) value?

(I am using Swift 3 with XCode 8)

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for `UIColor`?

Comment: Unwrap and then use `UIColor`'s `init(ciColor:)`?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert `CIColor` to `UIColor` like this:

```
var uiColor = UIColor(ciColor: ciColor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the initializers of [`UIColor`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicolor/1621938-init):

```
init(ciColor: CIColor)
```

This creates an instance of `UIColor` from a `CIColor`